# Angular: Set factory with data from $http? (Can't use $http.get inside a factory object?)

Tags: angularjs

I want to have a factory that returns a user from my database.

I am defining the factory like so:

```
angular.module('myapp')
  .factory('UserFactory', function ($http, $q, $cookieStore, AuthTokenFactory) {

    function profile () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.get('/getprofile')
        .sucess(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.reject(data);
        });

      console.log('something');
      return deferred.promise;   
    }; 

    var user = {
      profile: profile
    };

    return user;
```

However, later when I try to access properties of the user object, in a controller like so:

```
$scope.user = UserFactory;
```

And I try to access `user.name` (which is returned by my database) I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Why is this? Or, how do I set a property of a Factory with data from my service?

Comment: where are you assigning the `user` a `name` property? all I can see is that you are assigning a user a single `profile` property, which is a function.  You don't seem to be executing the function, but even if you did, it's not assigning any new properties to the `user` object....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'getprofile' method is asynchronous and it returns a promise. You need to assign user using the promise API:

```
UserFactory.profile().then(function(response) {
     $scope.user = reponse.data;
});
```

Also,  you don't need $q because $http() already returns a promise:

```
function profile () {
    return $http.get('/getprofile');
}
```

Comment: I like the idea but by putting the isReady function, he can handle in the view (if he wants to display some element when loading)?

Comment: for loading ui boxes, I wouldn't put it inside of a ready function. I would create a directive for that. Or perhaps use an $httpInterceptor

Comment: Yes yes yes, this it, and it works.  But two questions: If I then want to change the user information, (say from my controller where `UserFactory.profile()` is declared, how do I do that. In other words, am I able to read AND write the `UserFactory.profile().name` property? How can I sync it so that doing something in the controller, actually updates the property in the controller and the on the actual server?

Comment: Yes you can write to the user object that is on $scope

Comment: Thank you. And one more (related) question.  You mention that `$q` is not needed. I found this pattern online, but can it be done more succinctly (without the use of `$q`)?

Comment: `function getUser () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      if (AuthTokenFactory.getToken()) {
        $http.get('/me')
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
          })
          .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(data);
          });
      } else {
        return $q.reject({data: 'Client has no auth token'});
      }

      return deferred.promise;
    };`

Comment: I see you're providing an error message when rejecting a promise. That may be a good reason for using $q

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
angular.module('myapp')
  .factory('UserFactory', function ($http, $cookieStore, AuthTokenFactory) {

    var request;
    var user = {};

    user.ctrl = function(callback) {
      request = $http.get('/getprofile')
        .sucess(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          user.name = data.name;
         // etc
         return callback(user)
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          // handle your error
        });
       return request
    };
    user.isReady = function() { (!request) ? true : false };

    return user;
};
```

And then you can call the ctrl for 'create' the user and use isReady function to be sure than the http call is done or use the callback function.